# $\int_C\frac{e^z-1}{z^4}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

$$\int_C\frac{e^z-1}{z^4}dz$$
[image: this]

I'm just not following through with the math in this example when it turns $\frac{e^z-1}{z^4}$ into $\frac{e^z-1}{z^5}$

Comment: It is a typo; the power $4$ is intended to be $5$. See the [residue theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), which is what is being applied there.